# Best way to check row existence in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

This is not an issue but just my curiosity. Which of the following ways is the best to get an event row from the table and check if the user is its owner?

I have seen similar questions, but I would like to understand why one is faster than the other?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM event WHERE uid='".$user_id."' AND event_id = '".$id."'");
$checkCreator = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($query > 0) {
  //user is the event owner
}
```

or

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM event WHERE event_id='".$event_id."'");
$checkCreator = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if ($checkCreator['uid'] == $user_id) {
   //user is the event owner
}
```

Comment: Impossibly to tell from what you have given. What are the indexes on the tables. What is the cardinality of the index. Can a covering index answer your query.

Comment: suppose no indexes are set at all.

Comment: Well are you rows 512byte long or 65536kb long (not checking limits). You are not providing enough data to answer the question. How fast are you disks, what engine did you use, what type of rows, whats is the concurrency of the the requests. Are processes writing to the table - the list goes on and on - making your question moot really

Comment: Your lack of [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) is highly disturbing. If this code is on a public web site it's only a matter of time until you experience serious bugs or suffer a SQL injection attack.

Comment: I am using int casting or mysql_real_escape_string for escaping unwanted inputs

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, mysql_num_rows function is faster than mysql_fetch_array. But the correct answer will be seen after querying database.